Computed Property not updating when the value of the prop changes in vue 2
Im passing a prop and when its value changes im trying to update the computed property by using a watcher.
In my component i have a prop called
field: Object
computed
valueFromField() { return this.field.value; },
and watcher
valueFromField() { this.clonedField = _.clone(this.field); },
clone field is a data property
clonedField: undefined,
ive added console.logs everywhere, and in the template section i can see that the new value has been passed in however the watcher nor the computed gets triggered.
I was expecting the value to get updated

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. The watcher won't be triggered initially at least. " the watcher nor the computed gets triggered" - this suggests there's a problem with reactivity
